# Updating bookmarks in a range with strings, dependent on cell values in a range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to print information to a series of bookmarks in a Word document. The information is dependent on the values held in cells in a range.

**For example:**

- I have 5 bookmarks in a Word document.
  I have 5 cells in my Excel sheet, A1 to A5.
- The cell A1 corresponds to the first bookmark, A2 to the second, so on and so forth.
- The cell values are between 1 and 20.
  If the value in cell A1 is between 1 and 3 I want to return "Very Low".
  If the value in cell A1 is between 3 and 5, I want to return "Low", etc. etc.
  This should go on until a match is found.
- *When* a match is found, a string is printed at the corresponding bookmark for that cell and we move onto the next cell and the next bookmark.

I have only managed to alter the cell contents themselves and then print to a bookmark. I do not want to alter the cell contents.

Is there a way to print what returns from the `If`/ `ElseIf` to a bookmark?
How would this work for a range of bookmarks?

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Dim rCell As Range, rArea As Range

Set rArea = ws.Range("A1:A5")
For Each rCell In rArea.Cells
    If rCell.Value <= 3 Then
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value & " (Very Low)"

    ElseIf rCell.Value >= 3 And rCell.Value <= 5 Then
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value & " (Low)"
    
    ElseIf rCell.Value >= 5 And rCell.Value <= 10 Then
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value & " (Target)"
   
    ElseIf rCell.Value >= 10 and rCell.Value <= 20 Then
        rCell.Value = rCell.Value & " (Excess)"
    End If
Next rCell

' Print to bookmarks
With wDoc
    .Bookmarks("p1").Range = ws.Range("A1").Value
    .Bookmarks("p2").Range = ws.Range("A2").Value
    .Bookmarks("p3").Range = ws.Range("A3").Value
    .Bookmarks("p4").Range = ws.Range("A4").Value
    .Bookmarks("p5").Range = ws.Range("A5").Value
End With
```

Comment: Introduce a helper method that returns the desired output as a string, and print that to the bookmark.

Comment: @KostasK. I'm afraid I don't understand how that works for multiple objects in a range... that's probably my unfamiliarity with helper methods! Do you think you could elaborate on your comment?

Comment: @findwindow - Is that clearer? I can continue to edit the question until it makes sense to you.

Comment: Ah, why not just create variables?

Comment: @findwindow - Ah, that'll be because I am so new to VBA that I don't know how that would work in this context!

Comment: You declared and set 2 variables... Edit: KostasK's function is great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim r As Long
For r = 1 To 5
  With ws.Range("A" & r)
    Select Case .Value
      Case Is >= 10
        Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, .Value & " (Excess)")
      Case Is >= 5
        Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, .Value & " (Target)")
      Case Is >= 3
       Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, .Value & " (Low)")
      Case Is > 0
       Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, .Value & " (Very Low)")
      Case Else
       Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, "")
    End Select
  End With
Next
```

coupled with:

```
Sub UpdateBookmark(wdDoc As Word.Document, StrBkMk As String, StrTxt As String)
Dim BkMkRng As Word.Range
With wdDoc
  If .Bookmarks.Exists(StrBkMk) Then
    Set BkMkRng = .Bookmarks(StrBkMk).Range
    BkMkRng.Text = StrTxt
    .Bookmarks.Add StrBkMk, BkMkRng
    MsgBox StrBkMk & " bookmark updated with " & StrTxt, vbInformation
  Else
    MsgBox StrBkMk & " bookmark NOT found!" & StrTxt, vbExclamation
  End If
End With
Set BkMkRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you're using late binding, change wdDoc As Word.Document to wdDoc As Object and change BkMkRng As Word.Range to BkMkRng As Object

Comment: Hey @macropod - I'm having some problems. If there are blank cells in the range, none of the bookmarks are updated. Is there a way around this?

Comment: With what would you have them updated?

Comment: With blank values, just paste " " to the cell. I tried using `Case Else` and `Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, " ")` but that didn't work. Thank you

Comment: See updated code. Only a minor revision was needed.

Comment: I had tried that already (as mentioned), but it didn't work.

Comment: There are two changes to the Select Case code. Did you make both?

Comment: Are you talking about 
`Case Else
 Call UpdateBookmark(wdDoc, "p" & r, "")`

Comment: That's only the 2nd change - look at the preceding Case test also.

Comment: Yep, this doesn't work for me. Thank you for the answer, though. :)

Comment: It works for me. If it's not working for you, that's because you haven't defined the problem properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce a helper function that calculates the desired text based on the cell value and then print the returned value to the bookmark.

Keep in mind the numbers in your example overlap, for example 3 falls in both cases (very low & low) so update them as required.

A helper method that returns a string based on the cell value.

```
Private Function ToGrade(ByVal r As Range) As String
    Select Case r.Value
        Case 1 To 2:    ToGrade = "Very Low"
        Case 3 To 4:    ToGrade = "Low"
        Case 5 To 10:   ToGrade = "Target"
        Case 11 To 20:  ToGrade = "Excess"
        Case Else:      ToGrade = "Unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

---

Since both ranges run continuously, you can loop and concatenate their names:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 5 'or 20
    wDoc.Bookmarks("p" & i).Range.Text = ToGrade(ws.Range("A" & i))
Next i
```

Comment: And what if the Excel values are decimals? Moreover, your code doesn't reliably update the bookmarks - it simply inserts content *after* collapsed bookmarks.